# Comparing two strings using equals() causes NPE

Tags: java, android

My app crashes when I'm trying to compare two strings with `.equals()`.
The two Strings are in separate classes.

```
class Land {
    String land1;
    String land2;
    int a;
}

Land l = new Land();

public void check()
 {

     if(l.a==0){
         l.a=+1;}
     else if(l.a>0){
            if(l.land1.equals(l.land2)){ //and here is always crash
             toas_THE_FIELDS_ARE_EMPTY ();
            }};
```

where is problem ?

l.land1 and l.land2 have values

l.land1:

```
 public void show(){
     ImageView image;

             Random r= new Random();
     int i;
     i= r.nextInt(194)+1;
     image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

if (i==195){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="Vietnam";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.vietnam);
         }
```

.
.
.

l.land2 getting value from EDITTEXT

all code:

```
public class Flagi extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flagi);

    Button koniec;                                                      // Click LISTNER
    koniec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);                       // Click LISTNER
    koniec.setOnClickListener(myhandler3);                              // Click LISTNER
    Button start;                                                       // Click LISTNER
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);                        // Click LISTNER
    start.setOnClickListener(myhandler1);                               // Click LISTNER
    Button reset;                                                       // Click LISTNER
    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);                        // Click LISTNER
    reset.setOnClickListener(myhandler2);                               // Click LISTNER


}
Panstwo panstwo= new Panstwo();
View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {      // Click LISTNER
    public void onClick(View v) {                                   // Click LISTNER
        wyswietl();             
        sprawdz();
                // Click LISTNER

    }                                                               // Click LISTNER
  };                                                                // Click LISTNER

View.OnClickListener myhandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {      // Click LISTNER
    public void onClick(View v) {                                   // Click LISTNER
        zmien_tekst_dalej_na_start();                               // Click LISTNER
        zmien_flage_na_czerwona();
    }                                                               // Click LISTNER
  };                                                                // Click LISTNER

    View.OnClickListener myhandler3 = new View.OnClickListener() {      // Click LISTNER
        public void onClick(View v) {                                   // Click LISTNER
          System.exit(0);                                                       // Click LISTNER
        }                                                               // Click LISTNER
      };                                                        // Click LISTNER

      public void wyswietl(){
     ImageView image;

             Random r= new Random();
     int i;
     i= r.nextInt(194)+1;
     image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     if (i==0){
     image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pana);
     }

if (i==195){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="WIETNAM";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.vitnam);
         }
         if (i==194){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="WENEZUELA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.venezuela);
             }
if (i==193){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="WATYKAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.vatican);
         }
         if (i==192){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="VANUATU";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.vanuatu);
             }
if (i==191){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ZIMBABWE";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.zimbabwe);
         }
         if (i==190){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ZJEDNOCZONE EMIRATY ARABSKIE";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.zearab);
             }
if (i==189){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ZAMBIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.zambia);
         }
         if (i==188){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="JEMEN";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.yemen);
             }
if (i==187){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="WEGRY";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.wegry);
         }
         if (i==186){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="UZBEKISTAN";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.uzbekistan);
             }
if (i==185){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="STANY ZJEDNOCZONE";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.usa);
         }
         if (i==184){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="URUGWAJ";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.urugwaj);
             }
if (i==183){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="UKRAINA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ukraine);
         }
         if (i==182){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="WIELKA BRYTANIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.uk);
             }
if (i==181){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="UGANDA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.uganda);
         }
         if (i==180){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TUVALU";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.tuvalu);
             }
if (i==179){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TURKMENISTAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.turkmenistan);
         }
         if (i==178){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TURCJA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.turkey);
             }
if (i==177){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TUNEZJA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.tunisia);
         }
         if (i==176){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TONGA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.tonga);
             }
if (i==175){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TOGO";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.togo);
         }
         if (i==174){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TRYNIDAD I TOBAGO";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.tobago);
             }
if (i==173){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TANZANIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.tanzania);
         }
         if (i==172){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TAJLANDIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.tajland);
             }
if (i==171){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TADZYKISTAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.tajikistan);
         }
         if (i==170){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SZWAJCARIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.szwajca);
             }
if (i==169){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SYRIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.syria);
         }
         if (i==168){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SZWECJA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sweden);
             }
if (i==167){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SUAZI";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.swaziland);
         }
         if (i==166){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SURINAM";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.suriname);
             }
if (i==165){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SUDAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sudan);
         }
         if (i==164){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SUDAN POLUDNIOWY";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ssudan);
             }
if (i==163){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SRI LANKA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.srilanka);
         }
         if (i==162){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="HISZPANIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.spain);
             }
if (i==161){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SOMALIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.somalia);
         }
         if (i==160){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="WYSPY SALOMONA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.solomonis);
             }
if (i==159){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SAINT LUCIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.slucia);
         }
         if (i==158){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SLOWENIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.slovenia);
             }
if (i==157){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SLOWACJA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.slovakia);
         }
         if (i==156){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KOREA POLUDNIOWA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.skorea);
             }
if (i==155){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SINGAPUR";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.singapur);
         }
         if (i==154){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SIERRA LEONE";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sieraleone);
             }
if (i==153){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SESZELE";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.seszele);
         }
         if (i==152){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SERBIA";     
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.serbia);
             }
if (i==151){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SENEGAL";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.senegal);
         }
         if (i==150){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="WYSPY SWIETEGO TOMASZA I KSIAZECA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.saotome);
             }
if (i==149){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SAN MARINO";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sanmar);
         }
         if (i==148){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SAMOA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.samoa);
             }
if (i==147){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SALWADOR";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.salvador);
         }
         if (i==146){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SAINT VINCENT I GRENADYNY";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.saintvinc);
             }
if (i==145){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="SAINT KITTS I NEVIS";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.saintkits);
         }
         if (i==144){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="RWANDA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rwanda);
             }
if (i==143){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ROSJA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.russia);
         }
         if (i==142){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="REPUBLIKA POLUDNIOWEJ AFRYKI";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rpa);
             }
if (i==141){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="RUMUNIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.romania);
         }
         if (i==140){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KONGO";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rep_congo);
             }
if (i==139){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="PORTUGALIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.portugal);
         }
         if (i==138){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="POLSKA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.polska);
             }
if (i==137){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="FILIPINY";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.philippin);
         }
         if (i==136){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="PERU";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.peru);
             }
if (i==135){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="PARAGWAJ";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.paragwaj);
         }
         if (i==134){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="PANAMA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pana);
             }

if (i==133){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="PALAU";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.palau);
         }
         if (i==132){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="PAKISTAN";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pakistan);
             }
if (i==131){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="OMAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.oman);
         }
         if (i==130){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="NOWA ZELANDIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.nowa_zel);
             }
if (i==129){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="PAPUA-NOWA GWINEA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.nowa_gwinea);
         }
         if (i==128){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="NORWEGIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.norwegia);
             }
if (i==127){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KOREA POLNOCNA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.nkorea);
         }
         if (i==126){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="NIGERIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.nigeria);
             }
if (i==125){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="NIGER";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.niger);
         }
         if (i==124){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="NIKARAGUA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.nicaragua);
             }
if (i==123){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="NEPAL";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.nepal);
         }
         if (i==122){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="NAURU";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.nauru);
             }
if (i==121){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="NAMIBIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.namibia);
         }
         if (i==120){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MJANMA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.myanmar);
             }
if (i==119){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MOZAMBIK";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mozambik);
         }
         if (i==118){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MAROKO";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.morroco);
             }
if (i==117){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="CZARNOGORA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.monteneg);
         }
         if (i==116){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MONGOLIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mongolia);
             }
if (i==115){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MONAKO";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.monaco);
         }
         if (i==114){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MOLDAWIA";  
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.moldavia);
             }
if (i==113){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MIKRONEZJA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.micronesi);
         }
         if (i==112){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MEKSYK";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.meksyk);
             }
if (i==111){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MAURETANIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mauryt);
         }
         if (i==110){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MAURITIUS";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mauritus);
             }
if (i==109){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="WYSPY MARSHALA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.marshall);
         }
         if (i==108){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MALTA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.malta);
             }
if (i==107){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MALI";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mali);
         }
         if (i==106){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MALEZJA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.malezja);
             }
if (i==105){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MALEDIWY";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.maldives);
         }
         if (i==104){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MALAWI";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.malawi);
             }
if (i==103){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MADAGASKAR";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.madagas);
         }
         if (i==102){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="MACEDONIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.macedo);
             }
if (i==101){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="LUKSEMBURG";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.luksembu);
         }
         if (i==100){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="LITWA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lithua);
             }
if (i==99){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="LICHTENSTEIN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lichtenst);
         }
         if (i==98){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="LIBIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.libija);
             }
if (i==97){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="LIBERIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.liberia);
         }
         if (i==96){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="LESOTHO";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lesotho);
             }
if (i==95){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="LIBAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lebanon);
         }
         if (i==94){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="LOTWA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.latvia);
             }
if (i==93){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="LAOS";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.laos);
         }
         if (i==92){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KUWEJT";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.kuwejt);
             }
if (i==91){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KOSOWO";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.kosowo);
         }
         if (i==90){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KIRIBATI";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.kiribati);
             }
if (i==89){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KIRGISTAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.kirgistan);
         }
         if (i==88){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KENIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.kenya);
             }
if (i==87){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KAZACHSTAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.kazahst);
         }
         if (i==86){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KATAR";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.katar);
             }
if (i==85){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="JORDAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.jordan);
         }
         if (i==84){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="JAPONIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.japon);
             }
if (i==83){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="JAMAJKA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.jamajca);
         }
         if (i==82){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="WLOCHY";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.italia);
             }
if (i==81){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="IZRAEL";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.israel);
         }
         if (i==80){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ISLANDIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.islandia);
             }
if (i==79){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="IRLANDIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ireland);
         }
         if (i==78){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="IRAN";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.iran);
             }
if (i==77){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="IRAK";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.irak);
         }
         if (i==76){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="INDONEZJA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.indonesia);
             }
if (i==75){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="INDIE";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.india);
         }
         if (i==74){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="HONDURAS";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.honduras);
             }
if (i==73){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="HOLANDIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.holandi);
         }
         if (i==72){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="HAITI";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.haiti);
             }
if (i==71){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GWINEA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.gwinea);
         }
         if (i==70){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GUJANA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.guyana);
             }
if (i==69){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GWATEMALA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.guatemali);
         }
         if (i==68){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GRENADA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.grenada);
             }
if (i==67){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GRECJA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.grecja);
         }
         if (i==66){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GHANA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ghana);
             }
if (i==65){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="NIEMCY";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.germany);
         }
         if (i==64){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GRUZJA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.georgia);
             }
if (i==63){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GAMBIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.gambia);
         }
         if (i==62){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GABON";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.gabon);
             }
if (i==61){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="FRANCJA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.francj);
         }
         if (i==60){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="WYBRZEZE KOSCI SLONIOWEJ";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.foc);
             }
if (i==59){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="FINLANDIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.finland);
         }
         if (i==58){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="FIDZI";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fiji);
             }
if (i==57){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ETIOPIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.etiopia);
         }
         if (i==56){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="TIMOR WSCHODNI";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.etimor);
             }
if (i==55){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ESTONIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.estonia);
         }
         if (i==54){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ERITREA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.eritrea);
             }
if (i==53){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GWINEA ROWNIKOWA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.eq_gwine);
         }
         if (i==52){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="EGIPT";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.egipt);
             }
if (i==51){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="EKWADOR";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ecwador);
         }
         if (i==50){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="DOMINIKANA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.dominican);
             }
if (i==49){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="DOMINIKA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.dominica);
         }
         if (i==48){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="DZIBUTI";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.djibouti);
             }
if (i==47){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="DANIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.denmark);
         }
         if (i==46){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="CZECHY";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.czechy);
             }
if (i==45){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="CYPR";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cyprus);
         }
         if (i==44){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KUBA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cuba);
             }
if (i==43){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KOSTARYKA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.costarica);
         }
         if (i==42){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="DEMOKRATYCZNA REPUBLIKA KONGA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.congo);
             }
if (i==41){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KOMORY";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.comoros);
         }
         if (i==40){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KOLUMBIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.colombia);
             }
if (i==39){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="CHORWACJA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.chorwacja);
         }
         if (i==38){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="CHINY";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.china);
             }

if (i==37){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="CHILE";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.chile);
         }
         if (i==36){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="CZAD";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.chad);
             }
if (i==35){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="REPUBLIKA SRODKOWOAFRYKANSKA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cenafri);
         }
         if (i==34){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="REPUBLIKA ZIELONEGO PRZYLADKA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.capeverde);
             }
if (i==33){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KANADA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.canada);
         }
         if (i==32){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KAMERUN";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cameroon);
             }
if (i==31){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="KAMBODZA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cambodia);
         }
         if (i==30){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BURKINA FASO";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.burkinafaso);
             }
if (i==29){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BULGARIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulgaria);
         }
         if (i==28){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BRUNEI";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.brunei);
             }
if (i==27){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BRUNDI";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.brundi);
         }
         if (i==26){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BRAZYLIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.brazil);
             }
if (i==25){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BOTSWANA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.botswana);
         }
         if (i==24){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BOSNIA I HERCEGOWINA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bosnia);
             }
if (i==23){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BOLIWIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bolivia);
         }
         if (i==22){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="GWINEA BISSAU";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bissaugw);
             }
if (i==21){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BHUTAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bhutan);
         }
         if (i==20){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BENIN";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.benin);
             }
if (i==19){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BELIZE";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.belize);
         }
         if (i==18){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BELGIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.belgium);
             }
if (i==17){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BIALORUS";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.belarus);
         }
         if (i==16){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ANTIGUA I BARBUDA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.barbuda);
             }
if (i==15){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BARBADOS";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.barbados);
         }
         if (i==14){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BANGLADESZ";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.banglade);
             }
if (i==13){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BAHRAJN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bahrain);
         }
         if (i==12){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="BAHAMY";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bahamas);
             }
if (i==11){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="AZERBEJDZAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.azerbejan);
         }
         if (i==10){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="AUSTRIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.austria);
             }
if (i==9){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="AUSTRALIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.austral);
         }
         if (i==8){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ARMENIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.armenia);
             }
if (i==7){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ARGENTYNA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.argent);
         }
         if (i==6){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ARABIA SAUDYJSKA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.arab_sau);
             }

if (i==5){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ANGOLA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.angola);
         }
         if (i==4){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ANDORA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.andorra);
             }
if (i==3){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ALGERIA";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.algeria);
         }
         if (i==2){
             panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="ALBANIA";
             image.setImageResource(R.drawable.albania);
             }
if (i==1){
    panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo="AFGANISTAN";
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.afganistan);
         }

     zmien_tekst_start_na_dalej();
 };

 public void zmien_tekst_start_na_dalej(){
     Button button1;
     button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button1.setText("DALEJ");
 };

 public void sprawdz()
 {
     String a;
     String b;
     a=panstwo.wpisane;
     b=panstwo.wysietlone_panstwo;
     if(panstwo.a==0){
         panstwo.a=+1;}
     else if(panstwo.a>0){
            if(a.compareTo(b)==0)
             toas_THE_FIELDS_ARE_EMPTY ();
            }



    //punkty = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString()); //string to int



 };

 public void toas_THE_FIELDS_ARE_EMPTY (){                      // Toast_ empty fields
     Context context = getApplicationContext();                 // Toast_ empty fields
     CharSequence text = "DOBRZE";              // Toast_ empty fields
     int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;                         // Toast_ empty fields
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);     // Toast_ empty fields
     toast.show();                                              // Toast_ empty fields
      };                                                        // Toast_ empty fields
 public void zmien_tekst_dalej_na_start(){
     Button button1;
     button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button1.setText("START");
 };

 public void zmien_flage_na_czerwona(){
     ImageView image;
     image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 };

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.flagi, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
class Panstwo{
    String wysietlone_panstwo;
    String wpisane;
    int a;


}
```

}

Comment: it crashes because `land1` is null. Also `land2` is null btw

Comment: Where do you set the values for land1 and land2? Show us the code. Also, in general it is helpful to post the exception as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize land1 and lan2

```
class Land {
    String land1 = new String();
    String land2 = new String();
    int a;
}
```

Comment: Since strings are immutable you could as well use a literate: String land1 = "";